# redshift SQL anyway to count the item number of a Select statement

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Imagine there is a SQL statement with 300+ columns

```
create table if not exists (
300+ columns
);

Insert into
select
300 columns
from
a inner join b
on a.key=b.key 
;
```

It just keeps showing the error message

```
Invalid operation: INSERT has more expressions than target columns;
```

It is really hard to find which column is miss matching since there are too many columns.

Is there any way I can count the number of columns in a SELECT statement?

I know we can count the number of columns in information schema, but I want to count the number of columns/ items in a select statement, not an existing SQL table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use `information_schema` tables.  For instance, you could use:

```
create table tempt as
    select 300 columns
    from a inner join
         b
         on a.key = b.key;
```

(I would add something like `limit 1` because you may not care about the data.)

Then you can look in `information_schema.columns` to get the columns lists in order, with their types.  You can even compare the columns to the original table, using SQL statements.